# Why are the leaves on my money tree droopy?

Tags: diagnosis, watering, sunlight, repotting

The leaves on my money tree (*[pachira aquatica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachira_aquatica)*) are green and droopy. I do not water it often. I don't have it indirect sunlight. Is it not getting enough light?

Also if i wanted to repot what brand of soil mix should i get?

Comment: Hi Rose, welcome! For more accurate diagnosis you should post a close up picture of the leaves and one more general where we see pot and soil.